# Tiled background with header and footer

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tiled background graphic with a header and footer part. Something like this:

[image]

How can I use this as background for a android view? The middle part should repeat to fill the screen height (it should NOT stretch like in a 9-patch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you may need to convert the image to a [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) graphic.

### EDIT:

1. Use a [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html#decodeRegion%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) to get the region that is to be
   repeated as a Bitmap.
2. Create a [`BitmapShader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html#BitmapShader%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29) with `TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.REPEAT`.
3. Create a Paint and [set the bitmap shader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShader%28android.graphics.Shader%29).
4. Draw the bitmap using `canvas.drawRect()`.
5. Draw the header & footer separately.

Comment: A nine-patch will stretch the middle part. I want it to be tiled (repeated along the y-axis)

Comment: works, except step 4 should be canvas.drawRect instead of canvas.drawBitmap. canvas.drawRect will use the shader to fill the area of the rect. canvas.drawBitmap will draw the bitmap just once. Would be nice if you could edit your answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For the background you can try:

Place tiled_bg.xml at Drawable folder,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
<bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/tile_bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is my tile_bg.png

[image: tile_bg]

For the root layout you can use a RelativeLayout with background=tiled_bg

The heder with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

And the fotter with: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: nice, is it also possible to scale the tiled bitmap to the screen width using a layer-list drawable?

Comment: Do you mean place a drawable that covers the entire screen width?
I never test that. But in your example your tile_bg must be a portion of the red row.

Comment: yes, the red part should be repeated along the y-axis and be stretched along the x-axis